# Attributes of dumb groups

Tags: groups, smartgroups

In the table `civicrm_group`, I've noticed that even my non-smart groups have the fields `where_clause`, `where_table`, and `select_table` filled in. These don't seem necessary and cause a fair amount of slowness.

Is their a reason they exist, and is there a down-side to making those fields null in non-smart groups?

Comment: "and cause a fair amount of slowness" - I'd be interested to hear more - where/what speed improvement are you seeing when these are NULL?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you saying it's the cause of the slowness? Did you manually make them null and measured an improvement of the speed?

Comment: Yes. This was my method: I loaded a 14,000 record group five times. Load time averaged 30 seconds. I then made where_clause, where_table, and select_table NULL for that group and loaded the group 5 more times at an average of 23 seconds. To be fair, I have to concede that there may have been other variables at play since the site was online while I did this.